# Library dependancies not loading

Tags: javascript

The dependency core/jquery.ui is not loading into the theme. jQuery is loaded as it is included by default but jquery.ui refuses to load.

```
#theme.libraries.yml
popup:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/popup.js: {}
  dependancies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui
```

```
#theme.info.yml

libraries:
  - theme/popup
```

I have also tried attaching the library using the code below, but still no luck.

```
// theme.theme
function theme_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject();
  $is_admin = \Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute($route);
  if(!$is_admin) {
    $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'theme/popup';
  }
}
```

I have seen multiple references to core/jquery.ui throughout drupals files. So am a little confused.

I feel like i must be missing something obvious.

jQuery UI will load in fine if you are logged in, but again i believe this is included by default for admin users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are trying to use the built in jquery ui you must include -core/drupal.dialog as a dependency in your theme.libraries.yml for it to work

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in your theme.libraries.yml, dependancies should be dependencies.